# How to Restirct User to enter Only Spce,dot,apostrophe's and alphbets only using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a searching page in which i want to enter only alphabets,space,dot

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName, new { @placeholder = "Name", @id = "UserName", @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
$('#yourtextbox-Id').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32)
        return false;
});
});
```

same as u cal check charcode for dot comma etc